# How to sort an array by id or month: Descending (Latest Post First)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sorting, uicollectionview

I have a `UITableView` and a `UICollectionView` inside. I wanted to sort this to Descend (Latest Post First). How do I want to do this?, I tried a couple of methods and all are not working.

Following are my code and responses

```
  [Utilities serverRequest:@{@"getAnnouncement":@"a6dba37437ced2c3b07469fd6c0661f3"} completionBlock:^(id response) {

    collectionViewDic[@"announcement"] = response[@"response"];
   _annArray = response[@"response"];
   NSLog(@"AnnouncementResponse%@",response);

    // sorting to newest
   /*
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
    sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"anc_id" ascending:NO];
    NSMutableArray *sortDescriptors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    [_annArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
     NSLog(@"Sorted - AnnouncementResponse%@",response);
     */
    /*
    NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"anc_id" ascending:NO];
    NSArray* sortedArray = [_annArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
    NSLog(@"Sorted Array Response -%@",sortedArray);
    */
    announcmentDone = YES;
    if (newsDone && bulletInDone && announcmentDone && !refreshed) {
        refreshed = YES;
        [table reloadData];
    }
} errorBlock:nil];
```

[image: Response]

Comment: Please suggest me a code according to my response..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_annArray is actually an NSDictionary, with keys "September 2017", "August 2017" etc... The value of each key is then an array with a single NSDictionary in it as far as I can see. To get all the values you'd need something like:

```
    NSArray *responseValues = [response[@"response"] allValues]; // An NSArray of NSArrays
    NSMutableArray *dictionarys = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSArray *dictArrays in responseValues) {
        for (NSDictionary *dict in dictArrays) {
            [dictionarys addObject:dict];
        }
    }
    _annArray = dictionarys;
```

You should then be able to sort like you're expecting:

```
  NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"anc_id" ascending:NO];
  NSArray* sortedArray = [_annArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
  NSLog(@"Sorted Array Response -%@", sortedArray);
```

This is a quick, rough way of doing it though. In practise it would be far better to parse each block of JSON into an object, with type checking and sorting the objects.